# How do I open a file using its default application from Perl on Windows?

Tags: windows, perl, system

I have a directory of files that I would like to scan on a regular basis and execute with the default application they are associated with. They are not executable so system("file.torrent"); does not work. How are you able to run files with there associated applications in Perl?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

start

You could manually parse the relevant part of the registry, find the associated application, and kick it off yourself: but the command prompt's built-in start command life easier.

So, for your example you would simply do a system("cmd /c start file.torrent")

Comment: If the registry would now the associated app, he just could use the system() method for firing it up.

Answer (score 7):

The standard windows way is with [ShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153(VS.85).aspx).

In perl you can do it with, well, ShellExecute. Its in the [Win32::GUI package](http://perl-win32-gui.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/docs.cgi?doc=reference-methods).

Have not tried it. But it looks simple enough.

Answer (score 3):

Not Perl specific but you can always use the 'start' command.  The first argument will be the title of the new command prompt opened and the second argument is the file to open.

```
system('start "dummy title" "some file.doc"'); # opens the document in word
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option we use is

`system("RunDLL32.exe SHELL32.DLL,ShellExec_RunDLL file.torrent")`

Answer (score 0):

Never use system() on windows !
Crappy and bad method (PAS)

Answer (score 0):

Just to highlight the comment by  BeowulfOF above

```
system( "test.log" )
```

will open test.log in it's associated application just the same as entering

```
test.log
```

on the command line